# Lying awoke in bed pleasant. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I'm working with a book for English composition.
The book suggests "Lying awoke in bed pleasant" as an answer for a question
written in my language.

But I think the sentence is grammatically incorrect.
I think so because there is not a verb in that sentence.
Am I thinking wrong? Or if I write as the following, will it be correct?

> Lying awaken in bed is pleasant.

P.S. The question in the book includes meaning of "lying in bed after waking from sleep"

Comment: *Lying awoke* should be *lying awake*.  And yes, you need a verb like the one you supplied.

Comment: If *Lying* is the name of a person (not unreasonable in some communities / regions), then the sentence asserts that (s)he woke up in bed and was pleasant (as opposed to grumpy) upon waking up. So yes, it *can* be grammatical.

Comment: @Lawrence Stretches credulity a bit, but I see what you mean.

Comment: What's the intended meaning of the sentence?

Comment: @WS2 True :) . I suppose "Lying awoke" can also be read as a fancy way of saying "Lying there after being awakened".

Comment: It's impossible to know what the intended meaning is, but it is perhaps "Lying awake in a pleasant bed".

Comment: @Lawrence Except that would be *awoken*. *Lying (there) awoken*.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, good point. I'll go back to my original comment on this post.

Comment: Whatever, "Lying awoke in bed pleasant" is just plain wrong.

Comment: @HotLicks But quite an intriguing mental exercise to work out what the writer was trying to say.

Comment: @WS2 - If a book on English composition recommends the sentence "Lying awoke in bed pleasant" that book probably should be burned.

Comment: @HotLicks There are people who post here who would argue that if people say it, then it is English. You would be a prescriptivist in their eyes. I agree with you, by the way.

Comment: @WS2 - Yeah.  It's certainly the case that anyone can write anything they want (short of libel laws, etc), but the point is that this purports to be a book of *instruction* on English composition, and such books should at least conform to minimal standards of English.  If the book is as poorly written as the above suggests then it constitutes fraud.

Comment: @everyone - Your knowledge is the saving of me. Thank you.

Comment: @Jack0910 What is the title of the English composition book?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the sentence is grammatically incorrect, although it does contain a verb:

> **Lying** awoke in bed...

You are also correct in adding an "is" before "pleasant".

However, both you and the book may be confusing the words **awoke** (past-tense verb) and **awaken** (present-tense verb) with **awake** (adjective).

A possible solution:

> Lying awake in bed is pleasant.

Comment: And then you hope it is not too offending to people that suffer from insomnia...

Comment: Lying awake in bed may or may not be pleasant

Comment: Saying that "lying" is a verb is somewhat misleading. It's what's often termed a "gerund", which occupies something of a [middle place between a verb and a noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/205404/97555). While it does function as a verb within its clause (here "lying awake in bed"), it - or rather the verbal phrase - acts as a noun in the sentence as a whole. This is why you need to add the "is": while the clause has a verb, the sentence as a whole is lacking one.

Comment: @R.M. Hah! This is why I joined this community; to learn the strange particulars of the English language. Thanks for pointing that out. It took me a few reads, but I think I understand.

So, say you had the sentence "Swimming is fun". Is "Swimming" a gerund there, or a verb?

Answer (score -1):

This question has been answered. However, there is another possible variation, depending on the original question asked (which is unknown). Example:

- *Q: What are you doing?*
- *A: Pleasantly Lying awake in bed!*